# Windows cmd closes after ng serve --o command

Tags: angular, windows, npm, cmd

After I run:

`ng serve --o`

Windows cmd closes and i'm not to able to press `ctrl+C` to kill the angular app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an issue in `@angular/cli` version `12.0.0`.
Try installing the previous version (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli)

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@11.2.13
```

[image: cmd window closes after running ng serve]

Comment: Tried installing `11.2.13` globally, and after creating and serving a new app, the cmd window stays open. So this is definitely an issue with version 12.0.0.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20807

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: Well it's not a real "solution", but a workaround until the following issues [open - Closes cmd/powershell when opening url](https://github.com/sindresorhus/open/issues/236) and subsequently [angular-cli - cmd window closes after running ng serve --open](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20807) have been fixed in angular 12...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed now in angular 12.0.2